# A property of continuous bijective maps in the plane.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Take a non-empty open connected bounded set $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f:D\to D$ be a continuous bijective map. It is well known that $f$ could have no fixed points i. e. $f(p)\not=p$ for all $p\in D$.

I wonder if the following weaker property holds:
there is a point $p\in D$ such that $d(f(p),\partial D)=d(p,\partial D)$ where $d(z,\partial D)$ is the euclidean distance from a point $z\in \mathbb{R}^2$ to the boundary of $D$. Any existing reference in the literature will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My thanks to $\bf{ Moishe \ Cohen}$ for pointing out in the comments that my proof is finished upon observing that $g(p)=d(f(p),\partial D)$ is a bounded function on $D$ that converges to $0$ as $p$ approaches $\partial D$; therefore, $g$ attains its maximum for some $p\in D$.

Observe that $d(f(p),\partial D)=\inf\{d(f(p),x)\colon x\in\partial D\}$ is a continuous function of $p$. Hence, $d(f(p),\partial D)-d(p,\partial D)$ is continuous as well. $d(f(p),\partial D)-d(p,\partial D)$ maps into $[-R,R]$ for some $R>0$. Since $D$ is connected, the image of $D$ under $d(f(p),\partial D)-d(p,\partial D)$ is connected, and, hence, an interval as $D$ is bounded.

Thus, if there were **no fixed point** wrt distance from the boundary, then either $d(f(p),\partial D)<d(p,\partial D)$ or $d(f(p),\partial D)>d(p,\partial D)$ for all $p$ and conversely. We might as well use the equivalent condition $d(f^{-1}(p),\partial D)<d(p,\partial D)$ for $d(f(p),\partial D)>d(p,\partial D)$.

However, $d(f,\partial D)\colon D\to (0,\infty)$ achieves its supremum on $D$ as $d(f,\partial D)$ is bounded on $D$ and converges to $0$ as $p$ approaches $\partial D$. Suppose $p_0$ is a point where $d(f,\partial D)$ achieves its supremum on $D$. Then $d(f(p_0),\partial D)-d(p_0,\partial D)>0$ and $d(f^{-1}(f(p_0)),\partial D)-d(f(p_0),\partial D)<0$. Hence, there exists a point $p\in D$ such that $d(f(p),\partial D)-d(p,\partial D)=0$.

Comment: You are making things too complicated. The key to the proof is that function $g(p)=d(f(p),\partial D)$, $g: D\to (0,\infty)$ is bounded above (since $D$ is bounded) and converges to zero as $p\to \partial D$. Therefore, $g$ attains its maximum at some point of $D$.

Comment: I think that $\sup\{d(p,\partial D)\colon p\in D\}$ is attained because $\overline{D}$ is compact and $d(z,\partial D)=0$ iff $z\in \partial D$.

Comment: @RobertZ: Of course.

Comment: @studiosus Wow that's *really* embarrassing... Of course, you're absolutely right.

Comment: Good. Now just remove the staff about boundary fixed points (which is meaningless anyway since f is undefined on the boundary) and conclude that there is always a point while distance to the boundary is unchanged by the map.

Comment: I meant fixed wrt distance from the boundary by "boundary-fixed". A neologism in want of explanation, I admit. I had left it there because the answer is yours and I wanted to give credit to you unequivocally! I have edited the answer according to your desires.

Comment: The second formula in your 2nd-last sentence is just a re-statement of the first formula. I think what you mean to say is , with $E=\partial D$ and  $g(p)=d(f(p),E)-d(p,E) $ and $M=\max_{p \in D}g(p)=g(p_0),$ that since $f(p_0)\in D,$ we have $g(p_0)=d(f(p_0),E)-M\leq M-M=0,$ and that when $f(q_0)=p_0$ we have $g(q_0)=M-d(f(q_0,E)\geq M-M=0.$ Also this shows that it is sufficient that  $f:D\to D$ is a surjection, not necessarily a bijection. Your method also shows that the connectedness of $D$ is not needed.

Comment: Ugh. Retrospectively, parsing the notation I chose is unreasonably difficult. I wrote this during a caffeine fueled $24$hr paper writing marathon so you might be right!

I don't follow why, if $M=g(p_0)$, that $g(p_0)=-M+d(f(p_0),E)$? I only took a cursory look, but I think my answer is OK as it stands. You could just as well apply $f$ again to the first inequality in the penultimate sentence to get the latter one (using bijectivity, implicitly). IVT plus $D$ can't rip itself was my idea. I'd be very pleased if this holds with only surjectivity, however! I'll follow up when I get the chance.